# How can I apply blur effect on a background image in Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply a simple blur effect on the first row of my page that has a fullscreen background image.

The problem is, I am seeing shadows on the borders of the background image that aren't supposed to be there and on top of that, the logo that is positioned on top of the background image is being blurred too.

I understand I am blurring the `intro` div which in turn is blurring everything within it, so I must be applying the background image incorrectly as well.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

```
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Another row</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #191617;
}
.logo {
    width: 220px;
    margin-top: 10em;
}

.intro {
    background: url('../img/bg/bg2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/0334yL41/1/

Comment: create a pseudo-element on intro to emulate the background whitout affecting all the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `pseudoelement` to hold the background image without affecting other content.

To remove the dark edges, you can use `transform: scale()`. This will create scrollbars so you'll need to set `.intro` to `overflow: hidden`. You could also try remove the edges using positioning.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zg9e7es0/2/)

```
.intro {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/hNPuImp.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```